# Windows copy a file in the same subfolder but in different folders

Tags: windows, copy, xcopy

Okey, so here is my problem.

I have a folder with many user folders. I every use folder there is the same folder *subfolder1* and i want to copy a file to *subfolder1* so it looks something like this:

```
> C:\Folder\
>           user1\subfolder1
>           user2\subfolder1
>           user3\subfolder1
>           ...
```

and I want to copy file for every user in subfolder1. Something like this:

copy C:\Folder\File C:\Folder*\subfolder1\

In linux that would probably do the trick but in Windows I can't figure it out, so please if somebody can help I will be very grateful!

The operating system is Windows XP, but if really necessary I can do it on Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, so I have a breakthrough. I came up with this piece of code
`@echo off
for /D %%G in ("C:\Folder\*") do (
 copy "C:\Folder\File" "%%G\subfolder1\"
)`
but it seems to keep going forever and now I am trying to make it stop in the end, so if any of you have some suggestion please post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line, execute this:

```
for /D %f in (*) do copy my.file %f\subfolder1\my.file
```

If you put it in a batch file, replace `%f` with `%%f`

This is a `for` loop over directories, (`/D`) without recursion.

Comment: Thank you. So I almost got it. Now it runs and then ends eventually. Guess I don't need the brackets after `do`.

Comment: The brackets would be necessary if you were planning to execute more than one command.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. I always make such mistakes when comes to scripting. Thanks again for the help. :)